# Can not create an object from entity data model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 in visual studio 2010.
I created a an entity data model from a local database, but when I try to create an entity object with the name of the entity, the intellisense in Visual studio 2010 does not show any suggestions, and I can not create the object. 
for example, I created an entity data model with name "airlinesEntity", but I can't create an entity object from it. If anyone knows what is it that I am doing wrong or I need to do something more, please let me know. Thank you very much.

Comment: send your project code where you are facing the problem.

Comment: Did you reference namespace using `using` keyword ?

Comment: Is there any chance you might have installed VS2012 earlier and then uninstalled it? If so, then some of the dll's might have gotten corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you might have installed VS2012 earlier and then uninstalled it? If so, then some of the dll's might have gotten corrupted.

Comment: no, I have never installed VS 2012 before, but is it still possible that the dll files might have been corrupted nevertheless? and is there any way to fix it? or should I just uninstall and re install VS 2010?

Comment: You can just repair your VS 2010 if the dll files have been corrupted.